# R markdown adds # link behind HTML headers

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I've been trying to solve some HTML knitting issues. My HTML does not currently allow me to use HTML in the code, and thus I am unable to create tabsets.

However, while trying to solve that issue a new issue occured: My HTML output adds a clickable # behind each # Header.

I use the basic Rmarkdown format:

````
---
title: "Try"
output: html_document
---

/```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
/```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

## Including Plots
````

And then the output shows me this:

[image: HTML try]

Anyway have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature introduced in the current development version of **rmarkdown**. [See the NEWS file for more info.](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/NEWS.md#rmarkdown-25) To disable this feature, you may use:

```
output:
  html_document:
    anchor_sections: false
```